# Rearrange rows of pandas dataframe based on list and keeping the order

Tags: pandas, numpy

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'result':[-6.77,6.11,5.67,-7.679,-0.0930,4.342]}\
,index=['A','B','C','D','E','F'])
new_order = np.array([1,2,2,0,1,0])
```

The `new_order` numpy array assigns each row to one of three groups [0,1 or 2]. I would like to rearrange the rows of `df` so that those rows in group 0 appear first, followed by 1, and finally 2. Within each of the three groups the initial ordering should remain unchanged.

At the start the df is arranged as follows:

```
   result
A  -6.770
B   6.110
C   5.670
D  -7.679
E  -0.093
F   4.342
```

Here is the desired output given the above input data.

```
   result
D  -7.679
F   4.342
A  -6.770
E  -0.093
B   6.110
C   5.670
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `argsort` with `kind='mergesort'` to get sorted row indices that keeps the order and then simply index into the dataframe with those for the desired output, like so -

```
df.iloc[new_order.argsort(kind='mergesort')]
```

Sample run -

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   result
A  -6.770
B   6.110
C   5.670
D  -7.679
E  -0.093
F   4.342

In [3]: df.iloc[new_order.argsort(kind='mergesort')]
Out[3]: 
   result
D  -7.679
F   4.342
A  -6.770
E  -0.093
B   6.110
C   5.670
```

Answer (score 2):

pure pandas

```
df.set_index(new_order, append=True) \
    .sort_index(level=1) \
    .reset_index(1, drop=True)
```

[image]

***explanation***

- append `new_order` to the index

  - `set_index(new_order, append=True)`
- use that new index level and sort by it

  - `sort_index(level=1)`
- drop the index level I added

  - `reset_index(1, drop=True)`

Comment: Don't really understand the inner details of it, but tested and it works!

Comment: @Divakar hopefully that helps

Comment: So, that `sort_index(level=1)` part sorts in a way that keeps the order?